# Haskell conduit filter distinct values

Tags: haskell, filter, distinct-values, conduit

If I use the following `Source`:

```
 sourceList [1,3,3,1,2,3]
```

Is it possible to apply some filter or combinator to only allow distinct values to be passed downstream?

So in my example, only `[1,3,2]` would be passed downstream?

Comment: Is there nothing more you know about these values? It would be a lot easier to filter that list with some sort of metadata.

Comment: Note that a 'nub' conduit like this would not stream. It will use indefinite memory since one way or another the conduit will have to record what it has seen e.g. in a Data.Set.Set

Comment: @suffi in my case, the type is just a list of Ids

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-6.19 runghc --package conduit-combinators
import Conduit
import Data.Conduit.List (sourceList)

main = do
    print $ runConduitPure $ sourceList [1,3,3,1,2,3] .| myConduit [] .| sinkList

myConduit dup = do
  num <- await
  case num of
    Just x -> if x `elem` dup
              then myConduit dup
              else do
                yield x
                myConduit (x:dup)
    Nothing -> return ()
```

On execution:

```
sibi::casey { ~/scripts }-> ./cond.hs
[1,3,2]
```

Comment: For better algorithmic complexity, you could use a `Set` or `HashSet` instead, though that incurs an `Ord` or `Hashable` constraint, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-6.19 runghc --package conduit-combinators
import Conduit
import Data.Conduit.List (sourceList, mapAccum, catMaybes)
import Control.Monad (void)

main = do
    print $ runConduitPure $ sourceList [1,3,3,1,2,3] .| void (mapAccum foo []) .| catMaybes .| sinkList

foo :: Int -> [Int] -> ([Int], Maybe Int)
foo x dup | x `elem` dup = (dup, Nothing)
foo x dup = (x:dup, Just x)
```

On execution:

```
C:\Users\Gurkenglas\scripts>stack conduitnub.hs
[1,3,2]
```